# Which item was selected in a UICollectionView, if there 're multiple UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have more than one collectionView in a ViewController. The cell of those collectionViews has the same format.. so I'm reusing them. So my question is: How to identify in the method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
         didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

I don't want to do a couple of if's

I've found this solution everywhere, but really don't like it. Here is the code

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if let aCell = cell as? ItemCollectionViewCell{
        aCell.setupCell(with: self.items[indexPath.item])
    }

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == self.colletionViewTwo{
        // goto viewController1
    }else if collectionView == self.colletionViewOne{
        // goto viewController2
    }
}
```

Comment: You are told which collection view it was and which item it was (via the `indexPath`. What more are you looking for? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I know which item is via **indexPath.row** but I don't know which collectionView was selected

Comment: The collection view is the first parameter of the `didSelectItemAt` method.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I then I will have to make an **if collectionView == myFirstCollectionView** and I don't want that. I know it works, but looking for a more extendable solution

Comment: OK, so what is wrong with your simple `if/else` to determine which view controller to go to? It doesn't get any easier than that.

Comment: And why do you have two collection views that show the exact same types of cells using the exact same data at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create two classes that implement the collection view delegate and data source and use one of each. So you'll have these two extra objects in your current view controller.
2. Seeing your code now, the above is probably too heavy. Alternatively, add a dictionary in which you store the collection view as key and a selector as value. This is extensible as you say you want.

To be honest, what's your issue an `if` (or `switch`) statement like you have now?

Comment: So, I will have 2 `didSelectItemAt` in 2 different places ?

Comment: Yes. See other suggestion in answer.